# No engine is able to work with the template

Tags: symfony, pimcore

I'm trying to render a theme index file that I'm trying to import to pimcore to work with. I've put the theme folder in app/Resources/views.

I've added the following to my routing.yml file

```
index:
    path: /static/dist/index.html
    controller: AppBundle\Controller\indexController::index
```

below is my controller named  indexController.php

```
<?php
namespace Appbundle\Controller;

use Pimcore\Controller\FrontendController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class indexController extends FrontendController
{
    /**
    * @Route("/static/dist/index.html", name="homepage")
    */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('static/dist/index.html');
    }
}
```

When I try to navigate to localhost/static/dist/index.html, I get the following error:

```
No engine is able to work with the template "static/dist/index.html".
```

Comment: Did you install the [twig bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html)? Do you forget to add the twig extension to your filename, don't you?

Comment: Well the theme content is all in html, would I still need twig?

Comment: instead of adding a route you could just save the file into public/static/dist/index.html because the files in public are just delivered as is.

Comment: Jakumi is right. But if you want to understand your errror, you could start by reading the code of this render method you are calling.

Comment: `return $this->render('static'dist'index.html');` should throw a syntax error

Comment: @nico haase Oh that was a typo, meant static/dist/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Pimcore documentation specifies to use 1 of options:

- or render command returning string
- or template name in annotation returning array

Sample:

```
class DefaultController extends FrontendController
{   

    public function myAction()
    {
        return $this->render('content/default.html.twig', ["foo" => "bar"]);
    }

    /**
     * Example using the #[Template] attribute to resolve the view. 
     * The frontend controller also provides methods to add response headers or via attributes without having
     * access to the final response object (as it is automatically created when rendering the view).
     *
     */
     #[Template('/default/header.html.twig')]
     #[ResponseHeader(key: "X-Foo", values: ["123456", "98765"])]
    public function headerAction(Request $request)
    {
        // schedule a response header via code
        $this->addResponseHeader('X-Foo', 'bar', false, $request);
        
        return ["foo" => "bar"];
    }
}
```

See documentation here:

- https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/10.6/Development_Documentation/MVC/Controller.html
- https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/10.3/Development_Documentation/MVC/Template/index.html